# Sql Server 2008R2 XML export

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd

I have some trouble exporting data from our database to XML. I'm probably in over my head as i have no earlier XML knowledge but hey, how hard can it be :)

We already send this data through an excel sheet but now the customer wants it as XML instead. After upload to their system i can download it as an XML instead and below is a part of that file,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<PricatHead xmlns="xxxxx"
           preOrderTo="2015-06-01T23:59:59"
           name="15005-3"
           merchant="xxxx"
           customer="xxxxx"
           validFrom="2014-08-01T00:00:00"
           validTo="2015-06-01T23:59:59"
           currency="SEK"
           contractDiscount="0">
  <sprProduct itemID="86035-8"
              name="xxxx"
              description="xxxxxx"
              tax="0.00"
              eanCode=""
              eanType="EAN 13"
              color="BLACK"
              colorCode="C0100"
              size="36"
              sizeRange="EURO size"
              modelNo="86035"
              inSelection="N"
              productDiscount="0">
    <priceBracket quantity="1"
                  price="x"
                  grossPrice="xxxx"
                  validOrderDateFrom="2014-08-01T00:00:00"
                  validOrderDateTo="2015-06-01T00:00:00"
                  validShipDateFrom="2015-02-15T00:00:00"
                  validShipDateTo="2015-06-01T00:00:00"
                  type="PRE"/>
    <priceBracket quantity="1"
                  price="x"
                  grossPrice="x"
                  validOrderDateFrom="2015-02-15T00:00:00"
                  validOrderDateTo="2015-06-01T00:00:00"
                  validShipDateFrom="2015-02-15T00:00:00"
                  validShipDateTo="2015-06-01T00:00:00"
                  type=""/>
    <variantValue name="unit"
                  value="pcs"/>
    <variantValue name="recPrice_SEK"
                  value="x"/>
    <variantValue name="recCampaignPrice_SEK"
                  value="0"/>
    <variantValue name="brand"
                  value="x"/>
    <variantValue name="goodsClass"
                  value="4052"/>
    <variantValue name="recCampaignPriceCurrency"
                  value="SEK"/>
    <variantValue name="recWebPriceCurrency"
                  value="SEK"/>
    <variantValue name="unitType"
                  value="pcs"/>
    <variantValue name="x"
                  value="2603"/>
    <variantValue name="marketingInfo"
                  value="xxxxx"/>
    <variantValue name="preOrderDiscountHQ"
                  value="0"/>
    <variantValue name="grossPriceCurrency"
                  value="SEK"/>
    <variantValue name="productPicture_1"
                  value="xxx"/>
    <variantValue name="suppOrderCurrency"
                  value="SEK"/>
    <variantValue name="preOrderCurrency"
                  value="SEK"/>
    <variantValue name="productPicture_3"
                  value="xxx"/>
    <variantValue name="productPicture_2"
                  value="xxxx"/>
    <variantValue name="invoiceMethod"
                  value="net"/>
    <variantValue name="logisticUnit"
                  value="cu"/>
    <variantValue name="countryOfOrigin"
                  value="CN"/>
    <variantValue name="suppOrderDiscountHQ"
                  value="0"/>
    <variantValue name="customsTariffNo_SE"
                  value="6402999300"/>
  </sprProduct>
```

For the excel sheet i have an SQL proceedure that produces one big table with all the above data where `<sprProduct>` is one row and the rest columns.
I have no problem to create the `<pricatHead>` and the `<sprProduct>` tags but i fail with the `<priceBracket>` as they are also columns in the select statement and i have multiple columns that need their own `<priceBracket>`.
`<variantValue>` causes the same problem.

Difficult to explain but one sql row should produce multiple `<priceBracket>` and `<variantValue>`.

So far my code looks as below (shortened),

```
--Pricat HEAD
select 
PrisLista as [@name]
,gtinMerchant as [@merchant]
,gtinCustomer as [@customer]

--Pricat ROWS
,(  select 
    ar.ArtNr as [@itemID]
    ,ar.ArtBeskr as [@name]
    ,ar.ArtBeskrLong as [@description]
    ,prl.vat as [@tax]
    ,prl.quantity as [sprProduct/priceBracket/@quantity] 
    .........
    from prl
    for xml path ('sprProduct'), type)


from prh 
FOR XML PATH ('PricatHead')
```

How do i get each column for a specific row to produce its own tag with attributed values?

As a second question i also got an XSD schema for this XML file from the customer. Can this be used to help format the data exported from my database to match their required XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to nest priceBracket inside sprProduct then alias the selected XML column as `[sprProduct/priceBracket]`. To create attributes of nested nodes use the @ prefix, for example `[sprProduct/priceBracket/@quanity]`.

Here's a sample script that shows how to create the different arrangements you've mentioned.

```
select
    -- row level attributes
    1 as [@a],
    2 as [@b],
    3 as [@c],
    -- node level attributes
    4 as [sprProduct/@a],
    5 as [sprProduct/@b],
    6 as [sprProduct/@c],
    -- nested section
    (select 
        'a1' as [@a],
        'a2' as [@b],
        'a3' as [@c]
     for xml path ('priceBracket'), type),
    -- repeated nested section
    (select 
        'b1' as [@a],
        'b2' as [@b],
        'b3' as [@c]
     for xml path ('priceBracket'), type)
for xml path ('PricatHead'), type
```

In practice the sub-selects would join your source table to itself on the primary key in order to be able to access the columns in the same row as the outer select.

Comment: How about the XSD file? Is that somthing i should use for the export?

Comment: You *can* use XSDs with SQL Server XML data but it's not something I've done. You could start with [XML Schema Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187856.aspx) in the SQL Server docs and ask another question if you get stuck.